# How does the encryption methods work?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

Well, i was reading on encryption methods. I found out there are 3 types.

1. Hashing Encryption
2. Symmetric Methods
3. Asymmetric Forms

I am not understanding the hasing Encryption and some parts of AES in Symmetric method.

**Problem facing with Hashing Encryption ::**
I read -"*once the data is encrypted, the process cannot be reversed or deciphered*".
Than my question is why would some one use this method if you can only encrypt data but cant decrypt it? or am i getting it wrong?

**Problem facing with AES::**
Below is the code i found:

```
public class AES {

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;
    private static String decryptedString;
    private static String encryptedString;

    public static void setKey(String myKey) {

        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(key.length);
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
            System.out.println(key.length);
            System.out.println(new String(key, "UTF-8"));
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String getDecryptedString() {
        return decryptedString;
    }

    public static void setDecryptedString(String decryptedString) {
        AES.decryptedString = decryptedString;
    }

    public static String getEncryptedString() {
        return encryptedString;
    }

    public static void setEncryptedString(String encryptedString) {
        AES.encryptedString = encryptedString;
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            setEncryptedString(Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Each cipher encrypts and decrypts data in blocks of 128 bits using cryptographic keys of 128-, 192- and 256-bits, respectively..

So, in the code:

```
key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
```

its using 128 bit keys, right?

But whats base64 inside the encrypt and decrypt methods?

```
public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        setEncryptedString(Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
    }
}
```

Comment: hashing is used VERY frequently for storing passwords. if you (properly) hash passwords, it's (theoretically) impossible to figure out what the password originaly was, so stealing the hashes is (again theoretically) pointless.

Comment: can i decrypt it later on?

Comment: why are you asking? In your very own quote: "cannot be reversed or deciphered"

Comment: thats why i am confused. if i encrypt it and no one can figure it out but if later on even if i cant decrypt it myself than whats the point?

Comment: that's what encryption is for: hashing = one way, irreversible. encryption = two-way, reversible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashes are used mostly for verifying correctness of text.

### Example 1:

You have a hashed password. A person gives you a password. You want to check if he gave you the correct one. So you hash his password using the same algorithm. If you get the same hash that you have, it's the correct password.

**Advantage of hash**: you are not keeping the actual passwords, so if people hack into your database, they can't guess the real password.

### Example 2:

You are downloading a large file. You want to make sure that there were no errors in communication, and that nobody replaced the file with a different file that may contain malware.

The vendor who wrote the file gives you a hash of the file, separately from the file.

Once you download the file, you run the same hash algorithm on it. If you got the same hash that the vendor gave you, you know that you downloaded the correct file and there were no communication errors (at a very high probability).

**Advantage of hash**: it has few real-world collisions, so it's highly unlikely that a small change in the file will give you the same hash.

### Example 3:

Your company stores all the documents and files the employees use on disk, and doesn't want to store duplicates, because it wastes resources. So whenever any employee stores a file on the company document catalog, it needs to be checked to see if it's not a duplicate of an existing file.

For each file in the catalog you store its hash together with its details. When an employees adds a new file, you run the hash algorithm on the file. If the hash matches any of the existing hashes, it's (very likely) a duplicate. If not, it's a new file, and it can be stored.

**Advantage of hash**: It's a lot smaller than a file. Instead of comparing the whole file with all the existing files, you can compare short hash strings.

---

The reason you use base64 when you encrypt text is that encryption algorithms work on bytes, not on texts.

You convert the original text into bytes using an appropriate character encoding (in this case, `UTF-8`). But after you run the encryption algorithm, the bytes that you get back don't necessarily conform to any standard character encoding. There may be bytes there that represent control characters etc., or are not valid `UTF-8` values.

So in order to get some sort of readable string from it, you use base64 - which converts the encrypted bytes to a text that can be used even in old environments that only support ASCII.

To decrypt the text you first have to convert it back to bytes using the base64 algorithm, and then you can decipher it, and convert the deciphered bytes back into text using `UTF-8`.

Real text ➞ [UTF-8] ➞ bytes ➞ [CIPHER] ➞ encrypted bytes ➞ [BASE64] ➞ encrypted text

Encrypted text ➞ [BASE64] ➞ encrypted bytes ➞ [DECIPHER] ➞ bytes ➞ [UTF-8] ➞ real text

Don't confuse the "64" in the name of this encoding algorithm with the sizes of the keys and blocks you use in your cipher. That "64" simply stands for the fact that the bytes get translated to 64 possible characters (plus `=` as a special filler).

Answer (score 1):

I am not going through the code you provided, but will answer your question in the simplest possible way.

We would use hashing algorithm, if we want to save a password somewhere and keep in encrypted. Your question still holds, why would we do this? There is a slight twist in the plot, now when we need to authenticate using the hashed password, we do not reverse the hash, but hash the entered password and match it with the hash we have. This provides us a means to store a password somewhere in a way that the human readable password text cannot be reproduced (hash is ir-reversible).

Hope this clears out your confusion

Base64 is a encryption method, used to standardize many digital data stored and also change text to bytes, keeping it simple, it is a class that converts strings you store to strings composed of only 64 different characters(symbols) and their combination. To know more about base64, definitely google

Comment: Base64Encoding is not an encryption method

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say Encoding.
Will Correct. Thanks